# connection termination for cassandra with phantom

Tags: scala, cassandra

I'm trying out scala cassendra with phantom(websudos). here is my code.

```
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val hosts = Seq("localhost")
    val connector = ContactPoints(hosts).keySpace("demo")
    val i = connector.session.execute("select * from demo.events")
    println(i.all())
  }
```

This will dump the content in the table but program never exit.

However I put this code to a FlatSpec code work and exit properly.

```
 class SongsTest extends FlatSpec{
  "test" should "Test" in {
    val hosts = Seq("localhost")
    val connector = ContactPoints(hosts).keySpace("demo")
    val i = connector.session.execute("select * from demo.events")
    println(i.all())
  }
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: probably [`connector.session.close`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/Session.html#close())

Comment: or even [`connector.provider.cluster.close`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.html#close())  
Last time I had to use both

Comment: session.close did not work. But cluser close works. If you put it as a answer i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 
[`connector.provider.cluster.close()`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.html#close())

This behaviour is behind phantom library. 
I had the same problem for some reason with pure datastax java driver.

Test runner is probably calling `System.exit` at the end.